# =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(... only yielding headers

Tags: google-sheets-query, importrange

My ultimate goal is to use QUERY and IMPORTRANGE in order to pull data in a new sheet from 2 different sheets. For now, I am just trying to pull from 1 sheet to another. This is the formula I am using:

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1YRWamg6RKnyjo1rgWkn0Nl9BNamWlJp_CHsDbeSNfzA", "Form Responses 1!A:H"), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col8 WHERE NOT Col8 != 'I am not using an Ops phone today.'", -1)

This is only yielding the headers for the sheet I'm am trying to import data from help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, all i had to do was take out the "NOT"

New formula that works=

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1YRWamg6RKnyjo1rgWkn0Nl9BNamWlJp_CHsDbeSNfzA", "Form Responses 1!A:H"), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col8 WHERE Col8 != 'I am not using an Ops phone today.'", -1)